# Apache mod_proxy redirect with absolute domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I am using the example from apache to rewrite a url with proxy:

```
RewriteRule    ^widget/(.*)$  http://product.example.com/widget/$1  [P]
```

I want to set a absolute domain for this:

```
RewriteRule    ^de.domain.com/widget/(.*)$  http://product.example.com/widget/$1  [P]
```

But then it doesn't works. Where is the problem?

Comment: Try add `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^de.domain.com$` before `RewriteRule`

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` ?